# Como hacer que una imagen ocupe todo el alto de una celda combinada de una tabla que ocupa varias columnas y filas

Tags: html5, imagen, table

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de hacer que una imagen mucho mas grande que la zona que lo va a contener, ocupe todo el alto de una celda combinada de una tabla que ocupa varias columnas y filas.
He tenido varios resultados infructuosos probando tanto a meter codigo en html como en css, pero nada, el normal width="100%" height="100%" no sirve y el align tampoco me ha dado frutos, o la imagen ocupa un ancho desproporcionado, o se limita a la primera fila y no ocupa el resto.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:DodgerBlue;" colspan=6>Fecha Actual</td>
        <td>C_07</td>
        <td>C_08</td>
     <td>C_09</td>
     <td>C_10</td>
     <td>C_11</td>
     <td>C_12</td>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td class="principal" colspan=6 rowspan=6>
        <img align="center" width=300px height="100%" 
        src="../../05ImagenesJPG/BanderaFederacion.jpg" 
        alt="Bandera Federación">
     </td>
     <td>C_07</td>
     <td>C_08</td>
     <td>C_09</td>
     <td>C_10</td>
     <td>C_11</td>
     <td>C_12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>C_07</td>
     <td>C_08</td>
     <td>C_09</td>
     <td>C_10</td>
     <td>C_11</td>
     <td>C_12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>C_07</td>
     <td>C_08</td>
     <td>C_09</td>
     <td>C_10</td>
     <td>C_11</td>
     <td>C_12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>C_07</td>
     <td>C_08</td>
     <td>C_09</td>
     <td>C_10</td>
     <td>C_11</td>
     <td>C_12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>C_07</td>
     <td>C_08</td>
     <td>C_09</td>
     <td>C_10</td>
     <td>C_11</td>
     <td>C_12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>C_07</td>
     <td>C_08</td>
     <td>C_09</td>
     <td>C_10</td>
     <td>C_11</td>
     <td>C_12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>C_01</td>
     <td>C_02</td>
     <td>C_03</td>
     <td>C_04</td>             
     <td>C_05</td>
     <td>C_06</td>
     <td>C_07</td>
     <td>C_08</td>
     <td>C_09</td>
     <td>C_10</td>
     <td>C_11</td>
     <td>C_12</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Miguel, en la clase "principal" define el espacio que ocupan las celdas combinadas, después aplica a la etiqueta img un width del 100%.

```
.principal {
  max-width: 230px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo creo que es incompatible con:  tr, th, td {vertical-align:baseline;}